# Android Login Application

Tags: android, database, authentication

I want to develop a application that has a Login-like interface... instead of Username and Password it has a ProductKey Activation that when you successfully entered the product key the ProductKey Activation Window will not open again when the user reopen the application... can someone help me with this application.. THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR WHOM WANT TO HELP

Comment: Are you asking for code? We won't help much if you don't provide us with what you tried already. This is so easy to do I'm questioning myself why you ask it here. Just set a Boolean in a SharedPreference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dude, shared preferences and store the product key. Here, only for the first time it asks for the product key and for later instances it won't ask. Please mark it as answer if you are satisfied... Thanks

Comment: SharedPreferences myPrefs;
myPrefs = SignInActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
myPrefs.edit().putString("product_key",pKey.getText().toString()).commit();

Comment: i went to another problem... in sharedpref you can use the back button... and it will go back to the product key frame... is there a way that it will not come back to the product key frame?

Comment: dude, for that you need to finish the activity before moving to next using this.finish();

Comment: i want this kind of flow... product key activation -> main form -> sub form... when the sub form use back it will go to the main form and when i use the back from the main it will not be back at the product key form.. so do i have to put the this.finish() in the product key form right? please correct me if im wrong...

Comment: see, product key form is an activity right. So, through an if condition, check whether the product key is correct, if so launch your main form activity through intent and immediately finish the product key activity thats it...

Comment: i already done that... my problem is when i relaunch the appli and i press back it will go back to the product key form again

Comment: buddy, it won't go if you finish the activity.... "activity.finish()" will destroy the activity...

Answer (score 1):

Try to add programatically the **ProductKet TextBox**, before diplaying the Menu, verify if the product key has been entered : You can store it using [The shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)